# Is a Docker Hub Repository only for a single Docker File or multiple Docker FIles

Tags: docker, arm, dockerhub

Is a Docker Hub Repository only for a single Docker File or multiple Docker Files ?

I am unclear, in my case in my have two repositories one for an Intel build (using Automated Build), and another for an Arm build of the same application that I had to build locally and push to Docker Hub.

Is that how you are meant to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multi architecture & manifest it's possible to have many images for many architecture sharing the same tag.

I already answer one of your other post with this link : https://blog.slucas.fr/blog/docker-multiarch-manifest-hub-2/

Check this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/seblucas/alpine-homeassistant/), you can do a `docker pull seblucas/alpine-homeassistant:latest` for armhf, arm64 and amd64 without any problem (and each architecture will get its own image). The same is true for many other images provided by docker (alpine for example).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple Dockerfiles in a repository, by using tags. Each tag corresponds to a Dockerfile, so you could two tags one called `:intel` and another one called `:arm` in the same repository.

Comment: Okay. but I thought tags were for version control, i.e latest, version2, version3 ?

Comment: Both uses are OK, see for example the official image for nodejs: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/  They have tags for every version and every 'architecture'

Comment: okay I can tags for different versions and different types of linux (full/slim/alpine ecetra) but I cant see my use case tags for intel/arm - i assume these are all just intel only ?

Comment: The point is the same, in your case you could have tags like v1-intel and v1-arm

Comment: I understajd your point, but I have done some research and think this approach has now been supercdeded by the multiarch builds, look at your nodejs example yo can see their is also an Supported architectures section. This is how I shoud propelry support multiple architecures but  dont underatand how to doit, but that will be a different question.